# VBA Userform button image quality is poor

Tags: vba, button, userform

I have a VBA userform with images on all the buttons but for whatever reason the quality of the image on the buttons is terrible. In the attached image you can see the image that is being used on the left is nice and clear but once it gets put onto the button it gets all blurry and pixelated.  Is there a setting that can be changed to fix this?

[Button comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Huq.png)

Comment: I've had this issue before and I've never heard of a solution or of any such setting, no...

Comment: Have you tried to use smaller images so that VBA is not forced to scale the image down?

Comment: I had them close but I scaled them down even further and it did help.  There is still some pixelation around the edges of the picture though.  Seems like VBA is only running 256 color or something and everything else is full color.

Comment: I further cleaned up the images with gimp and exported them at 100% quality and it seemed to clean up a lot of the graininess that I was getting.